# Is it possible to install a higher version of python-numpy than 1.8.2 on a Raspberry Pi Zero?

Tags: raspbian, python, apt

I successfully installed most of the python data science packages on my RPi Zero using Geoff Boing's [excellent guide](https://geoffboeing.com/2016/03/scientific-python-raspberry-pi/#comment-34917).  However, the versions of some of the packages seem quite old.  E.g. `numpy.__version__` is '1.8.2' and scipy is '0.14.0'.

My system:

> Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)

If I do
`sudo apt-get upgrade python-numpy`

I get
`python-numpy is already the newest version.`

But the most recent version from Scipy is 1.15.

Is it a limitation of my OS or is 1.8.2 the most recent build for RPi or am I doing something wrong?

(My main issue is numpy 1.8.2 doesn't have various methods I want to use like `np.flip`).

Comment: As your OS is also "quite old" i.e. obsolete and unsupported this seems pointless!

Comment: in other words - update to *stretch* - however, even in stretch I think the "latest" version of python-numpty is `1.12.1` ... and looking further, in *buster* and *sid* it's `1.14.5` - so you'll need to look for some other way to get 1.15

Comment: Ah, so I need to update my OS.  Thanks for pointing this out.  Numpy 1.12.1 would be fine as the flip method was introduced in 1.12.0.

Comment: As nobody mentioned it; one way to update to the latest release of a package is to build from source. The [Numpy User Guide](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.4/user/) has a chapter on that matter...

Comment: In case anyone is interested, the advice above was good.  I installed Stretch and re-installed everything from scratch using apt-get and a few with pip3.  I also made the jump to python 3.5.3.  Now I have Numpy version 1.12.1, Scipy 0.18.1 and Pandas 0.19.2.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Python package manager Pip to get packages. These are not tied to a distributions packages. You may have to install it via `sudo apt-get install python-pip`.

To get numpy (1.15.4 at time of writing) you'll need the python dev packages `sudo apt-get install python-dev python3-dev`. You can omit python3-dev if you are stuck on python2.

Then you can fetch down numpy from pip either globally `sudo pip install numpy` or if you are using a python virtual environment (virtualenv) then just `pip install numpy` with the environment activated.

Bear in mind it takes a while to build numpy in this fashion. On a Pi 2 it took about 30 minutes so might take an hour or more on the zero.

Comment: Odd that so many people want to build this kind of packages from source (especially on models like the Zero). On Raspbian Stretch and Python 3 there are pre-compiled wheels available using pip3. And with a minimal bit of work you can also do the same on Jessie.

Comment: Upgrading the entire OS for one package seems like a worse use of time than having pip build this for you. If you feel you can detail the minimal work needed it sounds like problem solved.

Comment: Add /etc/pip.conf (see https://www.piwheels.org/). And it's a good idea to leave Jessie behind soon anyway. Updates will end soon... And IIRC it takes a lot more than an hour to build numpy on a Zero.

Comment: I'd make that an answer, looks like it's a neat solution. Nice work.

Comment: I think I already did that for other questions. Not sure though. I'll have a look